# How to add mouseenter listener to div inside xtemplate

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a dataview with an xtemplate, and I want to display a window when the user hovers over a particular image within the template. The usual trick to just check the class of the item clicked doesn't work, because the "itemmouseenter" event is only fired when the mouse enters the item, and not again until it exits the whole item and comes back again.  So thus, I have no way of checking if it then goes over the picture once it has entered the object.  How do I assign the itemmouseenter event to the specific div? I've tried doing it right in the html, but I can't figure out how to get around the "function not defined" error I get whenever I put the onmouseenter="hoverFunc", since I'm referencing a function outside of the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a delegated listener:

```
view.el.on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log('go');
}, null, {
    delegate: 'img.someCls'
});
```